# UWP ListView how to control item height - area around the ListViewItem

Tags: xaml, listview, styles, height, win-universal-app

I have a simple test app I am using to figure out my ListView issues. I have two things I need to accomplish beyond what I have now.
1. Get the spacing between ListViewItems to be less than the default. I can't seem to figure out where this is styled.
2. I have IsEnabled="False" and that gets me the behavior i want, user cannot interact with control. But, I don't want the item to be faded. Wondering what attribute I need to tweak to make this happen.

Thanks for any help!

```
    <Grid x:Name="GridBase" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" MinWidth="400">
    <Grid Margin="30,20" Background="LightGray">
        <ListView x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsItemClickEnabled="False" Width="{Binding ElementName=GridBase,Path=Width}" MinWidth="400" MaxWidth="1200" IsEnabled="False">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.Header>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="LightGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ElementName=MyList,Path=Width}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Col1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Col2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Col3" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Col4" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Col5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="Col6" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="Col7" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="7" Text="Col8" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="8" Text="Col9" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Aquamarine" Width="{Binding ElementName=MyList,Path=Width}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Column1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Column2}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Column3}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Column4}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Column5}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Column6}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding Column7}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding Column8}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="8" Text="{Binding Column9}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get the spacing between ListViewItems to be less than the default and you should make the ListViewItem's margin and make the top or buttom be less.

Answer (score 1):

To solve 1. You can just adjust the margin of the ListviewItem by adding

```
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="-10,-10,-10,-10"/>
```

to the `<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">`

To solve 2. Set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` in your ListView.